# How to keep @PathVariable parameter name after obfuscation by Proguard

Tags: java, spring, proguard, obfuscation

I am using Spring framework for Rest Service.  I have one Rest API below which has @PathVariable id.  But after Proguard obfuscation , the parameter 'id' is changed to something like 'parama' which causes the REST not work because it doesn't match the definition in @RequestMapping.   How can i resolve it to keep the parameter name?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getAccount(@PathVariable int id) {
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-keepparameternames` keeps the parameter names in the "LocalVariableTable" and "LocalVariableTypeTable" attributes of public library methods.

Here is my proguard configuration:

```
-keepparameternames
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*
-keepclasseswithmembers class test.rest.controller.* {
    public <methods>;
}
```